# CSS speech popup and internal list separator

Tags: html, css, popup, border

I'm trying to create that kind of speech popup with an internal menu.

Each item of the menu is separated by a border. When there's an odd number of items inside the menu, things are ok, but when there's an even number of items, how can I extend the border inside the speech pointer ?

After some thought, I must also take in consideration the possibility to scroll the menu items inside a fixed popup size. It will be perfect if the item border follows the scrolling inside the speech pointer too. (of course in that case the popup will be open on the right of the parent button instead of left)

[image]

### [The codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNpwXQ)

or

### The code snippet

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: #7F7F7F solid 1px;
}
.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: -15px;
  top: 105px;
}
.bubble:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  border-color: transparent #7F7F7F;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  right: -16px;
  top: 105px;
}

.list {
  margin:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  margin:0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height:59px;
  
}

.item:last-child {
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble" style="border-color: rgb(127, 127, 127); width: 100px; height: 240px; top: 55px; border-radius: 0px; border-width: 1px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <div class="pointer" style="content: '';position: absolute;border-style: solid;border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;display: block;width: 0;z-index: 1;right: -15px;top: 105px;">
  </div>
  <div class="pointerBorder" style="content: '';position: absolute;border-style: solid;border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;border-color: transparent #7F7F7F;display: block;width: 0;z-index: 0;right: -16px;top: 105px;">
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add your current code so far ?

Comment: @vals current code posted

Comment: even better if you write a codepen for this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you are using the `.pointer` and `.pointerBorder` elements, you don't need the `:before` and `:after` `pseudo-elements` on the `.bubble` to make the arrow.

Secondly, since your arrow will always be vertically centered to the `.bubble`, you should align it vertically to be more flexible:

```
.pointerBorder,.pointer {
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
}
```

You should also get rid of the set height on the `.bubble` since it's height is defined by it's content.

After that changes, you will have a perfectly vertically aligned arrow on your box.

Now, the truth is that you cannot extend the border, but you can give the illusion that the border extends into the arrow. You can do this by adding a `pseudo-element` on the `.pointer`

```
.pointer:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  top: 0px;
  left: -17px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

If your number of items is fixed and it's even then you are ok, but if the items varies, you have to add a class to the `.bubble` so you could know if there is an even or odd number of items in it. This is something that should be done on your server side script, or via `JavaScript`. *(You can skip this part for a `CSS` only approach but you'll have to change your `HTML`)*

So the complete code looks like this:

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: #7F7F7F solid 1px;
}
.list {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 59px;
}
.item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.odd_items .pointer:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  top: 0px;
  left: -17px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.pointerBorder,
.pointer {
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  position: absolute;
}
.pointer {
  border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
  right: -15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.pointerBorder {
  border-color: transparent #7F7F7F;
  right: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble odd_items">
  <div class="pointer">
  </div>
  <div class="pointerBorder">
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems impossible to add a vertical scroll bar inside the speech popup and make the items (and the border) move according to the scroll

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Τhe truth is that I forgot about it, ^_^ But, I'll have a look to it today.

Comment: I found the property [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) that may be useful, but it doesn't have very good support. I also am pretty sure that you could wrap it with an [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) but I don't know much about svg.